# How to execute codeigniter controller in cron

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I have a problem running a codeigniter controller as cron.
I have created a cron from cpanel which will execute every 2 minites.

The command i used is

```
php /home/myusername/public_html/index.php welcome
```

the cron executes but the logic inside welcome controller is not executed. I.e

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'hi';
    }

}
?>
```

instead of printing "hi" it prints the html code of my home view. 
i have set in route

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Site';
```

and in "Site" controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller
{
     public function index()
     {
          ...
          ...
          $this->load->view('site/home', $data);
     }
}
?>
```

So when it executed the html for site/home is printed.

When i tried with the shell with command

```
php /home/myusername/public_html/index.php welcome
```

It executes correct and it prints "hi".

Comment: Everything looks ok, and it's certainly strange that you would get different results the same code executed in command line or cron. Maybe there's a problem with your cron syntax and 'welcome' isn't getting picked up so the request gets directed to the default controller?

Comment: yes , but i am stuck with this and cant find out what i am missing

Comment: Try to create a second function in your welcome controller called test() that echoes 'test' and then try that in a new cron entry that calls php /home/myusername/public_html/index.php welcome test

Comment: I have created function test but result in same - printing the html for home view

Comment: Try calling it from the cron like I suggested

Comment: yes the same command i have used still the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138602/discussion-between-pacio-and-bharat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
php /home/myusername/public_html/index.php welcome index
```